# Dynamically views on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, view

I have a question regarding views on postgresql.

We have two views on two different schemas. One called "first" and the other one is called "second".
We need the view "first" to be created and always have the same content as the view "second". When i say content i mean the query that constructed the view and not the result of the view.

In summary: query of view first changes->query of view second changes

Is something like this possible?

If you need more details you can ask me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A VIEW is just a hardcoded SELECT statement. When the underlying table(-s) change, the result from the VIEW changes. When there is another VIEW selecting data from the first VIEW, that result will also change. What you want, is how it works. Just try.

Comment: @FrankHeikens . Thank you for you answer. Via code the "first" view changes a lot of times in a day so we need those changes to also occur to the "second" view dynamically every time somethings changes to the "first" view. We need to connect them with some way

Comment: @FrankHeikens the "second" view doesn't select data from the "first" view. We just need two identical views that when a change occur to the query of the "first" we need that change to apply to the query of the "second".

Comment: When you want to change the view definition, based on DDL changes of another VIEW or TABLE, an event trigger could be of help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html

Comment: If you change the definition of `v1` the engine won't change the definition of `v2` by itself. You'll need to manually change the definition of `v2` to match the new logic.